# Creating Key Bindings for an Xbox One controller on Mac

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, macos, keyboard

I am really looking for a way to create key binding for an xbox one controller connected to a Mac. I know this is kind of a weird request, but I really want to try playing Guild Wars 2 with a controller. While, granted, it is probably better to use a keyboard and mouse, I really want to try it with a controller, but this game does not support a controller. I was wondering if there was any way to create key bindings to the Xbox One Controller buttons.

For instance: left stick as WASD and ABXY for 1234. Combinations would be helpful as well, like Rt + A = 5, and that sort of thing. I have a driver for the controller, but that is only useful for compatible games on steam and OS X. I am currently using Xone-OSX from FranticRain on Github, but am open to other programs.

Comment: Xpadder  is typically mentioned for doing this, but I don't know if it works on Mac, and I have no experience with it to make an answer. I definitely suggest using the new action cam setting for playing with a controller.

Comment: I've managed to do this using the Steam Controller, by adding a 'Non-steam game' shortcut and mapping the controller to the keyboard controls.

Answer (score -2):

Joystick Mapper is an app on the Mac app store that allows you to map your controller. It has 3 stars and is 5 dollars. Here's the website: https://joystickmapper.com/.